# Laravel looking for the wrong table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.6

I have specified the table name in the model class.
Laravel 5.6, PHP 7

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class SizeProduct extends Model

{
    protected $table = 'size_product';

    protected $fillable = ['product_id', 'size_id'];
}
```

This is my migration:

```
class CreateSizeProductTable extends Migration
{

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('size_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
        //some code here
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('size_product');
}
```

But i still get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db_name.product_size' doesn't exist
```

Comment: Are you using the SizeProduct model?  There's no reason for it to be using product_size if you are...

Comment: You must have some mention of `product_size` somewhere else in your code. Laravel isn't going to make up table names by itself.

Comment: What's your actuall request? What's the table name in db? Show your migrations.

Comment: Do you migrate the migration classes with command `php artisan migrate`? if already exist `php aritisan migrate:refresh`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe **sizeproduct** is your pivot table for `manytomany` relation, so as described here, The pivot table is derived from the **alphabetical order** of the related model names (so in your case product comes first).

You can change it in relation defining code:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Size::class,'size_product');
}
```

Or you may prefer to create separate migration for your pivot table.